# iphone notes app that supports Dropbox sync, search, import text files automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, dropbox

I search for a notes application that supports

- File sync with Dropbox folder
- Searching the contents of the text files
- Import new files from Dropbox folder automatically

I found an app that claims to have those features, called [Locayta](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locayta-notes/id393819477?mt=8). But on my iphone which has iOs 7.1, importing new files from Dropbox folder doesn't work.

I wonder if there are any other notes apps that support these features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently use [Simplenote](http://simplenote.com) to sync with my [nvAlt](http://brettterpstra.com/projects/nvalt/) on my Mac. While Simplenote is doing the syncing, you can configure SimpleNote to also sync to Dropbox, or you can have nvAlt store the files in Dropbox on you Mac.

A little more in line with your question, I have used [Notesy](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/notesy-for-dropbox/id386095500?mt=8) in the past. It uses Dropbox for syncing, and nvAlt could still access the files via Dropbox on my Mac. However, It was very slow to search, and I recall it had several other annoyances. I haven't tried recent versions, so it might be better.

Comment: Thank you very much. I installed SimpleNote and nvAlt. They work as you describe. New files to the synced Dropbox folder are automatically imported into Simplenote.